# How many ways can a student opt for three subjects given the restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a question regarding a combinatorics problem. A college offers $8$ subjects for the undergraduate course. A student can opt for any three subjects. So there are total in total $\binom{8}{3}$ subjects combinations. However there are certain subject restrictions. A student can not opt Geography and History,  Anthropology and Hindi,  English and Education,  English and Hindi together. Consequently how many subject combinations will be there?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Hint: Subtract off the number of pairs that can't happen.  For example, how many combinations include geography and history?  Be careful of subtracting the same combination twice, however.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's how I would do it - definitely need care when subtracting off the English and Hindi combinations for example so you don't remove the case of English, Hindi and Anthropology off twice say.

Comment: That's what I need... How many combinations will involve English and Hindi together? How to find this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: @J.Yomcha If you pick both English and Hindi together, how many subject choices would be left available to you?

Comment: @Ben that would be 6 choices. With this calculation there would be 6+6+6+6=24 restricted combinations. Is there any risk of having the same combinations in within this 24 combinations?

Comment: @J.Yomcha  There is, so we need to add those cases to the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, there are $$\binom{8}{3}$$ ways to choose three of the eight subjects without restriction.  From these, we must subtract those cases that involve a prohibited combination.

If a student had opted for one of the four prohibited pairs of subjects, he or she would have $8 - 2 = 6$ choices for the third subject in his or her undergraduate course.  Hence, we must subtract these $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{1}$$ choices.

However, if we do so, we will have subtracted some combinations twice, once for each way of designating one of the pairs of prohibited subjects as the prohibited pair.  We only want to subtract those cases once, so we must add them to the total.

To illustrate, a student who has not taken the restrictions into account could select Anthropology, English, and Hindi.  We have subtracted this case twice, once we designated Anthropology and Hindi as the prohibited pair of courses with English as the additional course and once when we designate English and Hindi as the prohibited pair of courses with Anthropology as the additional course.  The other case we have subtracted twice is the selection Education, English, and Hindi.  Hence, we have subtracted two selections twice.

Therefore, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of undergraduate courses a student is permitted to select at the college is

> $$\binom{8}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{1} + 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Total 3 subject combination = C(8,3)

From this we need to subtract the number of unwanted combination = 3*NumU

*"NumU" is no of combinations where a particular forbidden paid appears(say  Geography and History)*

Number of combinations where both Geography and History are chosen = C(6,1)

C(8,3)-3*C(6,1) = 112-18 = 94

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).